# Pythonic syntax for appending an arbitrary class object list property

Tags: python

Is there an analog of `setattr()` that allows for appending an arbitrary list property of an instantiated class object? If not, is there a recommended way of doing so?

This is a trivialized version of what I'm doing currently:

```
foo = SomeClass()
...
attr = "names"
value = "Eric"
values = getattr(foo, attr)
values.append(value)
setattr(foo, attr, values)
```

This seems clunky and inefficient.

Edit: this assumes that foo.names (or whatever arbitrary value might be assigned to the attr variable) is in fact a list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `setattr` call is redundant, *if* `foo.names` is indeed a list (if it's something else, could you please clarify?).  `getattr(foo, attr).append(value)` is all you need.